# Coordinates of screen touch aren't working

Tags: ios, objective-c, coordinates, touchesbegan

So I'm trying to get the coordinates of a screen touch. Here is the code I'm using:

```
UITouch *touched = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
location = [Touch locationInView:touched.view];
NSLog(@"x=%.2f y=%.2f", location.x, location.y);
```

All I need to test for is the Y coordinate, so I'm printing out the Y coordinate on the screen to see what it's saving as the `location.y` and right now it's saving it as 0.000000

How do I get this to work properly so it's not saving 0 as the location.y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depend of your views hierarchy.

I will assume you meant

```
location = [touched locationInView:touched.view];
```

and not

```
location = [Touch locationInView:touched.view];
```

If you want the location in your controller view, you should use

```
[touched locationInView:self.view];
```

Your `touch.view` can refer to a subview of your view hierarchy in which the coordinate could be 0, 0.

EDIT: It seem issue was just related to `Touch` instead of `touched`

Comment: ok thank you for the tip on `touched` instead of `touch` that made the coordinate work correctly